# URLs nas tags doctype e html

Tags: html, html5, dtd

```
1) <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

2) <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Com o HTML5 foi removido o uso das URLs nas tags `<!DOCTYPE html>` e `<html>`, mas para cada tipo de *Doctype* havia uma URL diferente, assim como na *html*.

Qual era a real finalidade das URLs nas tags citadas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O HTML é uma linguagem que DERIVOU do SGML. Antes do HTML5 as convenções do HTML tentavam manter as mesmas normas do SGML, fazendo com que um arquivo HTML fosse ao mesmo tempo um arquivo SGML. Porém, com a popularidade do HTML (que até então era o formato SGML mais utilizado no mundo), afim de "facilitar a vida" dos desenvolvedores, os navegadores ficavam cada vez mais flexíveis quanto à sintaxe da linguagem HTML.

Como os princípios guias para a elaboração do HTML5 foram compatibilidade, utilidade e interoperabilidade, foi aberta a discussão sobre flexibilizar a linguagem, resultando em uma linguagem próxima da SGML, mas com alguns "quebra-galhos".

Apesar de parecer pouco representativo, estas mudanças contribuem para a redução de tráfego e simplifica a linguagem, tornando-a menos rigorosa.

Quanto à sua dúvida:

**1. DOCTYPE**

Um arquivo SGML bem definido, traz uma informção chamada DTD (Uma Definição de Tipo de Documento - Document Type Definition (DTD)). Esta informação define e valida a estrutura, elementos e atributos presentes em um arquivo XML e ela é definida através de declaração .

O DTD pode ser completamente definido dentro do arquivo do arquivo SGML ou pode ser referenciado. No caso do HTML a prática mais comum (talvez exclusiva) era refererênciar este DTD.

Ao passar do tempo, a liguagem HTML foi amadurecendo e alguns elementos foram sendo incorporados e até modificados, sendo necessário definir variações das estruturas disponíveis.

Para ver a lista de declarações mais comuns e sua principais características veja: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

Após muita discussão sobre a estrutura do HTML5, o W3C definiu o HTML como uma liguagem com características próprias, abandonando definitivamente o padrão SGML (apesar das características ainda serem bastante semelhantes). Sendo assim convencionou-se, por questão de compatibilidade, que a declaração  deve ser usada para identificar um arquivo HTML. A declaração  é necessária em um arquivo. [http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#syntax-doctype]

Para mais informação sobre DTD: http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/

**2. XMLNS**

Já o atributo XMLNS serve para evitar conflito em nomes de elementos e atributos em arquivos XML. Lembre-se a linguagem XML deriva diretamente da linguagem SGML, assim como o HTML derivava. Então, a não ser que você esteja usando XHTML, o atributo XMLNS não faz qualquer efeito em HTML. [http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#xmlns-namespace]

Espero ter sanado sua dúvida.